# SVM libraries for complex input

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm, complex-numbers

I would like to use SVM libraries for a university project.
As the field of research is signal processing, the data consists of
complex vectors: **X** is in **C^n**.
Matlab functions (svmclassify) apparently doesn't support complex input.
Does anyone know if it is possible to sue libSVM for that purpose? any other 
possibilities?

Comment: Can't you just encode the complex into a vector form?

Comment: Do you mean R^2n instead of C^N? In some of the papers I have seen (I am not an expert here) it is stated that it is not a good idea. There is cross information that cannot be ignored.

Comment: I would also suggest to do R^2N.

Answer (score 1):

None of libraries I know allow direct usage of complex numbers as it is very **unusual** approach. Although in the same time most of the libraries (libsvm in particular) let you directly include the Gram (Kernel) matrix, so you can use any type of object, including complex vectors.

Simply compute the kernel matrix `K_ij = K(x_i,x_j)` where `K` is the scalar product (in the sense, that implies semi positive definite matrix `K`) of your complex vectors `x_i` and `x_j` (and `x` is training set). And that's all you need - easy and generic approach.

Comment: Thanks, lejlot - I will do that.  Can you elaborate a little on why this approach is considered unusual? I am new to SVM

Comment: Well complex numbers are rather unusual representation in any machine learning model. SVM, Neural Network, Decision Trees - they were designed with the R^n data in mind. Obviously there are some modifications and complex generalization of some of them, but it is somewhat contradictory to the whole concept of features. As suggested in the comment - complex number is actually just a pair of real numbers, with some custom way of expressing similarity, which does not really include any special depth or strength but complicates the whole idea- so why bother?

Comment: how about discrete fourier decomposition with amplitude and phase shift represented as a complex number?